# Парсинг разных видов предложений

Tags: java

Есть текст, в нем надо найти вопросительные, восклицательные и утвердительные предложения. При это следует, каждое предложение добавить в коллекцию. То есть, после парсинга, должна быть коллекция только с утвердительными предложениями,  коллекция только с вопросами и т.д. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо проверить текст на совпадения регулярным выражением `\s*([^!.?]+?([!.?]))`.
У каждого вхождения в первой группе захвата будет само предложение, а во второй - соответствующий символ пунктуации. Предварительно заводишь словарь из трёх списков строк и в нужный список добавляешь предложение.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, это предложение "У каждого вхождения в первой группе будет само предложение, а во второй - соответствующий символ."

Comment: "Метчишь текст на регулярку" - а что это значит?

Comment: @0xdb, `match` это значит. Надеюсь, он в джаве как-то так же называется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, как-то так - `matches()`.